# How would you go on proving Law of Excluded Middle with Quantifiers?

Tags: logic, proof, quantification

The following obviously follows true from no premises, but I can't seem to find a formal proof to it unfortunately.

∃x ∀y (¬P (y) ∨ P (x))

Comment: That is an odd way of formalising the LEM. I would write ∀x,P: ¬P(x) ∨ P(x) or even ∀p: p ∨ ¬p. You don't prove it, is an axiom (in some logic systems; not in all).

Comment: You are right but I thought adding the existential quantifier would be fairly simple this is true when x=y. I somehow couldn't do this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

We need *LEM* : **∀zP(z) ∨ ¬∀zP(z)**

Proof by cases (or **∨**-elim) :

1) **∀zP(z)** --- assumed [a]

2) **P(x)** --- by **∀**-elim

3) **¬P(y) ∨ P(x)** --- by **∨**-intro

> 4) **∃y∀x (¬P(y) ∨ P(x))** --- by **∀**-intro followed by **∃**-intro

5) **¬∀zP(z)** --- assumed [b]

6) **∃z¬P(z)**  --- equivalent

7) **¬P(y)** --- assumed [c] for **∃**-elim

8) **¬P(y) ∨ P(x)** --- by **∨**-intro

> 9) **∃y∀x (¬P(y) ∨ P(x))** --- now we may discharge [c] by **∃**-elim from 6)

From 4) and 9) we conclude with :

> > **∃y∀x (¬P(y) ∨ P(x))**

by **∨**-elim with *LEM*.

---

We may "verify" it through some equivalences. Consider :

> **∀x (A ∨ P(x)) ↔ (A ∨ ∀x P(x))**;

with it, we may rewrite the original formula : **∃x ∀y (¬P (y) ∨ P (x))** as :

> **∃x (∀y ¬P (y) ∨ P (x))**.

Then we need the equivalence :

> **∃x (A ∨ P (x)) ↔ (A ∨ ∃x P(x))**

and we rewtite the last formula as :

> **∀y ¬P (y) ∨ ∃x P (x))**

which in turn is equivalent to :

> > **¬ ∃y P (y) ∨ ∃x P (x)** --- *LEM*.